# List subcategories of active parent category (WooCommerce)

Tags: categories

I want to list out the child categories when on the parent category page.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<?php
                        $cat_id = get_query_var('product_cat');
                        get_cat_ID($cat_id);
                        $args = array(
                            'current_category' => 0,
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                            'title_li' => '',
                            'current_category' => $cat_id,
                        );
                        wp_list_categories($args); 
                    ?>
```

For example, if I'm on iPhone Parts (product category), I want to display only child categories of that category and not all of the other categories, because at the moment... it's still displaying the other parent categories (samsung parts & sony parts).

Thanks!

---

EDIT

So this is how I did it:

```
<?php
                        $cat = get_queried_object();
                        $cat_id = $cat->term_id;
                        $args = array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                            'title_li' => '',
                            'child_of' => $cat_id,
                        );
                        wp_list_categories($args);
                    ?>
```

:)

Comment: Answered this one myself. See final code.

Comment: you edited your question to include the answer.  You should edit your question so it is a question, and put your answer as a separate answer